# resize div width on window resize

Tags: javascript, css

For a site I'm building now the logo has a centered font with two white lines coming off and extending to the edge of the window, regardless of the window size.

I figured out that the easiest way to do it is to get javascript (through jquery) to resize the div whenever the document is loaded or the window is resized. My code looks like this.

```
$(document).ready(cssFix);
$(document).ready(stripeSize);
$(window).resize(stripeSize);

function cssFix() {
     $('#leftstripe').css({position: 'absolute', top: '84px'});
     $('#rightstripe').css({position: 'absolute', top: '35px'});
}

function stripeSize() {
     $('#leftstripe').width($('#logo').offset().left + 110);
     rightOffset = $(window).width() - ($('#logo').offset().left + $('#logo').outerWidth());
     $('#rightstripe').width(rightOffset + 183);
}
```

Everything works ... when the window is loaded or resized the bars line up with the logo perfectly. The problem I'm having is that when the window is resized by dragging the line sort of jumps around before settling down once the window size is set. Not a smooth resize, in other words.

Is there anyway to avoid this?

Comment: let me guess... your using IE? have you tried it in FF?

Comment: I use a debounce plugin ... what browser are you using? It's probably sending resize events so often that the code is doing it too quickly. Try this on for size http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce/docs/files/jquery-ba-throttle-debounce-js.html

Comment: @Patrick it does the same thing in both webkit (Safari, Chrome) and Firefox.

Comment: @drachenstern I bet that will work, or at least decrease the problem. I'll try that later tonight when I work on the site again.

Comment: then yeah... its not just the browser... its bouncing.  -> drachensterns comment will probably help.

Comment: Lemme know if it is and I'll put it as an official answer.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a 100% wide white outer div with a centred inner div with the logo?

This way you can code it only whit CSS and avoid JavaScript entirely.

You can find an example of what I mean [here](http://jsfiddle.net/deJus/).

Comment: Tried that but the problem is that the stripes on the left and right don't have a consistent width OR a consistent percentage width.

Comment: @birarda: You shouldn't care what the width of the stripe is: if you set your DIV to be 100% wide it will stretch to fill its container, and if you centrer the inner DIV it will position itself automatically (it should be done through `margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto` if I remember correctly). You'll have problems only if the logo is not centred. maybe I'm misunderstanding your question, do you have a working example?

Comment: @Albireo nothing up yet as an example.
I think I tried what you're describing with a wrapper div at width 100% and then the logo was centered in the page. The problem is that the stripe doesn't go through the whole page ... there's a stripe on the left and a stripe on the right side so it's more where to stop it that's causing the problem.

Comment: @Albireo here's a screenshot of the header.
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1864924/lemy.png

Comment: @birarda: The stripes are extending to the edge? If yes, you could "cut" them from the logo and place them in a different image - let's say - 5000px wide, keeping the "line position switching" in the centre. Then you could use something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/JUSww/) and place the image as the background (centred!) on the outer div. The result should be exactly as your logo, but it will "stretch" up to a page width of 5000px.

Comment: @birarda: You can find [here](http://jsfiddle.net/deJus/) quick example of what I mean, if you widen or narrow the frame (or the whole page) you see that the stripes always fill the whole page, and the logo stays in the centre. The misalignments are due to the quick job, and can be fixed easily.

Comment: @Albireo that looks like it might work although there is a max width at which that won't work right, depending on the size of the images with the stripes that you use.

Comment: @birarda: If you set as the background an image 5000px wide, I think you can be *pretty sure* it won't break up... On the other hand, you'll never be able to obtain a 100% success rate in every condition from now to the eternity...

Answer (score 0):

Try using this kind of trick.. make an outer block with thick border and place logo inside of it with negative margin-top:
http://jsfiddle.net/Qf2sT/

html:

```
<div class='lines'><div id='logo'><img src='http://www.google.com.ua/images/logos/ps_logo2.png' /></div></div>
```

css:

```
body { background: black }
.lines { width: 100%; border-top: 10px solid white; margin-top: 60px }
.lines #logo { margin: 0 auto; width: 364px; margin-top: -60px; }
```